# Android setting Google Analytics as exception handler in entire Application

Tags: android, google-analytics

I'm using the newest version of Google Analytics for Android (v4). I'm trying to get it to report uncaught exceptions and crashes in the entire application. Is this possible, or do I have to do it Activity by Activity? What about crashes that aren't occurring in an Activity's thread?

Here's my Application's onCreate method.

```
    @Override
public void onCreate() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate();

    Tracker tracker = this.getTracker(TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);

    UncaughtExceptionHandler myHandler = new ExceptionReporter(
            tracker,                                        // Currently used Tracker.
            Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(),      // Current default uncaught exception handler.
            this);                                         // Context of the application.

        // Make myHandler the new default uncaught exception handler.
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(myHandler);
}

  public enum TrackerName {
    APP_TRACKER, // Tracker used only in this app.
    //GLOBAL_TRACKER, // Tracker used by all the apps from a company. eg: roll-up tracking.
  }

  HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker> mTrackers = new HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker>();

  public synchronized Tracker getTracker(TrackerName trackerID) {
      if (!mTrackers.containsKey(TrackerName.APP_TRACKER)) {
          GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
          Tracker t = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker);
          mTrackers.put(TrackerName.APP_TRACKER, t);
      }

      return mTrackers.get(TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
  }
```

Inside my global_tracker.xml file, I have `<bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>` set. I can't tell what else needs to happen in order to set the global exception handler.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem with the exact same setup - all other tracking works, but no exceptions are reported.  Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately I did not.

Comment: I am having a same problem. If you have a solution for this problem, post it. Thank you